# Alternative to Appcenter / HockeyApp for hosting mobile applications

Tags: xamarin, uwp, software-distribution, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I am looking for an alternative to HockeyApp, so that I can host and deliver Xamarin Application to end customers (UWP, iOS, Android). The reason I cannot use HockeyApp is that the authentication mechanism has changed and requires one of github, microsoft, google, etc credentials to register/login. The end customers with their business emails, should not be using personal logins to access enterprise stuff.
Have checked tools like TestFairy, etc. None of them serve the purpose or are missing UWP app hosting.

Comment: Actually, you can distribute apps with App Center without requiring users to login. All they need to download the app is a publicly accessible link. You can set it up in Groups under Distribute tab.

Comment: @rubo That is true for "public" links, but I ran into the same issue as a client needed to use their company addresses to control access and AppCenter does not support 3rd-party OAuth2 and requiring enterprise users to use non-enterprise/public logins just does not fly (nor does AppCenter support 3rd-party/self-hosted git servers, another nail in that coffin....)

Comment: AppCenter is absolute garbage. Avoid it all costs.

Answer (score 1):

Your customers can create Microsoft account with their business email. It's free. Not tied to outlook.com email address. They will benefit from improved security compared to the deprecated HockeyApp authentication.

Answer (score 0):

you can create google account with office email, suppose for your business you use oultlook.com, with the same id you can create account on google only thing is gmail will not be there for you because you already have outlook, but you can use all google service with this account.